# When to use @RequestMapping, @GetMapping and @PostMapping in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

On my home page I want to populate the tables with data from the database.
Page home.html:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-dark" id="userTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col"></th>
                                    <th style="width: 20%" scope="col">Title</th>
                                    <th style="width: 60%" scope="col">Description</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="nota:${notas}">
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                        th:onclick="javascript:showNoteModal(${nota.getId()},${nota.getTitle()},${nota.getDescription()})">Edit</button>

                                        <a class="btn btn-danger"
                                        th:href="${/eliminarNota(notaId=${nota.getId()})}">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <th scope="row" th:text="${nota.getTitle()}">Example Note Title</th>
                                    <td th:text="${nota.getDescription()}">Example Note Description </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

What annotation should I use in the method the class Controller:

```
@Controller
public class InicioController {
    private NotaService notaService;
    public InicioController(NotaService notaS){
        this.notaService = notaS;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/inicio")
    public String obtenerDatosUsuario(Model model,FormNota formNota){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with server rendering frameworks like thymeleaf, its controllers can be divided into two groups for a better understanding:

- Controllers to show the page content to your client
- Controller to receive actions from your client

#### Show page content

Here @RequestMapping and @GetMapping are usually used. The main goal of this controllers is "merge" the html template with data from anywhere like a database:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/home" })
public class ViewController {

@Autowired
private StudentService service;

    @GetMapping
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        List<Student> studentList = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("studentList", liststudent);
        model.addAttribute("someField", "foo");
        return "home";
    }

}
```

#### Receive page actions

In this case @PostMapping is usually used.

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String submissionResult(@ModelAttribute("personForm") Person person) {
        return "result";
    }

}
```

#### Samples

- https://riptutorial.com/thymeleaf/example/29269/form-submission
- https://github.com/dariawantech/spring-boot-thymeleaf-example

Comment: Thank. It was very helpful. I am new to Spring Boot, I am practicing with a project.